# batch script for xcopy

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a simple batch script to copy a folder to another folder.

```
@ECHO OFF
IF %1.==. GOTO INFORM
XCOPY  %1 D:\CopyLoc /D /E /C /R /I /K /Y
ECHO Copied
GOTO EXT
:INFORM
ECHO USAGE: CUSTCP <SOURCE DIRECTORY>
:EXT
```

I have saved this file under the name `custcp.cmd`.

When I say

```
C:\>custcp
```

I get the message `The syntax of the command is incorrect.` But what I want is to display `USAGE: CUSTCP <SOURCE DIRECTORY>` message. Is there any other novel way of doing this? Also I want to know if this command will work for folders in mapped network drives?

PS:This is my first attempt at batch file creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `<` and `>` are redirection characters, batch wonders where you want to redirect the text to.

Use a caret (`^`) directly before the redirection characters to turn off their special meaning, thus:

```
ECHO USAGE: CUSTCP ^<SOURCE DIRECTORY^>
```

Comment: Additional question: Does xcopy command work for Network drives? I know we can map network drive and supply that as a argument. Like `XCOPY Z:\SOURCE C:\DESTINATION`. But can we do it without mapping it to a drive? like `XCOPY \\SharedPath\SOURCE C:\DESTINATION` ?